# create a result set difference between two tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table suppose `products` and `auto_assign_prod_list`. I want to populate a dropdown list with the id of products table that are not present in auto_assign_prod_list table.

Suppose, 
product table contain

```
Id
------
1
2
3
4
5
```

auto_assign_prod_list table contain

```
Id
-----
1
5
```

So, my result set will be

```
2
3
4
```

How is it possible using MySQL and PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `left join`

```
select p.id
from products p
left join auto_assign_prod_list a on a.id = p.id
where a.id is null
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb842/2)

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: First of all Thanks juergen d for answering. But I used this but this was not show my desired result. It only show the result of first table. Please help me that is there a another way to solve this issue !!

Comment: Are you sure? Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id FROM product
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM auto_assign_prod_list)
```

It will select the ids from `product` table which are not in `auto_assign_prod_list` table.

Result:

```
Id
------
2
3
4
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ca361/1).

Comment: Hi Raging Bull, thanks for help me, I try this in the SQL section in phpmyadmin but it shown the result set of the first table 1 2 3 4 5 not 2 3 4, I don't know why this is happen, could you pls help me